# Get path to CGridView images from external javascript

Tags: javascript, image, yii, assets, cbuttoncolumn

I have an external js file, where I manually add a row to the table generated by CGridView.

My question is how to pass the path to the images in CButtonColumn (like the `update` or `delete` button)? I dont want to use the fixed path, cause when I move it to another server it may result in wrong paths (assets folder may change right?).

Comment: Where are your images? You mention the assets folder. Are you publishing them through the asset manager?

Comment: Well my javascript images are in my modules assets folder and then they are published to main appliation assets folder. Images for gridview are placed in one folder in app main assets. But I guess this folder will change after moving app to different server machine.

Comment: Are all your images in one directory and do you publish that complete directory? Or do you publish each image file separately?

Comment: @MichaelHärtl - default CGridView images (which are `delete, update, view`) are placed in one single folder, but my images, that I use in CGridView (like `stats` or sth) are placed in different folder (I guess those folders are created when those images are needed first time only).

Comment: I don't quite understand. Your answer implies that you have no idea how the images are published, but they somehow end up in the assets folder. So there's nothing to worry about. If you need them in js, just read out the `src` attribute with jQuery.

Comment: @MichaelHärtl - actually I don't know how they are published. When I use default GridView images in view (while defining CButtonsColumn) - I dont have to define the path for them. When I create new row in javascript (external file) - it won't be resolved by itself. More than that - in js code - I add row with one default image button and one custom. So there are two asset urls right?